# Dask: How to merge 2 dask df without multiplying the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dask

I have 2 dask dataframes with the following shape.

historical_trans_ddf: (29,112,361, 14)

train_ddf: (201,917, 6)

after merging: (18,030,009, 19)

From my understanding, merging using left join would return the row of left df, which is 201k rows. Somehow, I got 18M rows from merging.

This is how my 2 dataframe look like.
historical_trans_ddf:

```
 authorized_flag|        card_id       |city_id |category_1 |installments   |category_3 |merchant_category_id   |merchant_id    |month_lag  |purchase_amount    |  purchase_date    |category_2 |state_id   |subsector_id
        Y            C_ID_4e6213e9bc        88       N              0             A               80         M_ID_e020e9b302           -8      -0.703331         2017-06-25 15:33:07        1.0      16         37
```

train_ddf:

```
    first_active_month  |    card_id    | feature_1 | feature_2 |feature_3  |target
    2017-06-01           C_ID_92a2005557    5              2           1    -0.820283
```

I want to join by using card_id column. My code for joining is the following:

```
merged_train_ddf =  train_ddf.merge(historical_trans_ddf, how='left', on='card_id')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)- instead use [formatted code blocks](/help/formatting)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Alright, fixed!

Comment: any chance you messed up naming dataframes somewhere?

Comment: @NoobVB I rechecked, and it was not the error. I named some of the dataframe here wrong, if that what you mean. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: if it does not take too long, try merging the opposite way... just for curiosity :)

Comment: What do you mean by "merging the opposite way"?

Comment: like this `merged_train_ddf =  historical_trans_ddf.merge(train_ddf, how='left', on='card_id')`

Comment: I found an solution. Use group by function

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the solution, `group by` will do the trick preventing the rows from multiplying. Use this code before merging.

```
historical_gb_pdf = historical_trans_pdf.groupby("card_id")
historical_gb_pdf = historical_gb_pdf["purchase_amount"].size().reset_index()
historical_gb_pdf.columns = ["card_id", "num_hist_transactions"]
```

Comment: .groupby() without any aggregation method returns a DataFrameGroupBy object. I don't think this solves your problem. Any chance you could post a complete example? see this guide: [mre]

Comment: I edited the code to answer. I dont fully understand the code, so I wont be able  to  explain  it to you because I took it from someone else, but it works.